# Can I do a Twig import in a loop?

Tags: twig

Is there any way I can do an import in twig with a loop?

For example i have a code that looks the following where `all_widget_file_names` is the array of filenames

```
{% if 'dwtext' in all_widget_file_names %}
{% import "dnkn/widgets/dwtext.twig" as dwtext %}
{% endif %}

{% if 'dwpassword' in all_widget_file_names %}
{% import "dnkn/widgets/dwpassword.twig" as dwpassword %}
{% endif %}

{% if 'dwradio' in all_widget_file_names %}
{% import "dnkn/widgets/dwradio.twig" as dwradio %}
{% endif %}

{% if 'dwcheckbox' in all_widget_file_names %}
{% import "dnkn/widgets/dwcheckbox.twig" as dwcheckbox %}
{% endif %}

{% if 'dwmultiselect' in all_widget_file_names %}
{% import "dnkn/widgets/dwmultiselect.twig" as dwmultiselect %}
{% endif %}

{% if 'dwtextarea' in all_widget_file_names %}
{% import "dnkn/widgets/dwtextarea.twig" as dwtextarea %}
{% endif %}

{% if 'dwselect' in all_widget_file_names %}
{% import "dnkn/widgets/dwselect.twig" as dwselect %}
{% endif %}

{% if 'dwform' in all_widget_file_names %}
{% import "dnkn/widgets/dwform.twig" as dwform %}
{% endif %}
```

Can I make something like this

```
{% for filename in all_widget_file_names %}

{% import "dnkn/widgets/"~filename ~".twig" as filename %}

{% endfor %}
```

I know the import statement dosen't take a value of the variable after `as`? Do I have any other way to make this code cleaner ?

Comment: If you’re looping over `all_widget_file_names`, you don’t need to check if `filename` is in `all_widget_file_names`.

Comment: Yea, thats right. Thank you. Cleaned. But thats not my question

Comment: That’s why I didn’t post it as an answer, but only as a comment. :)

Comment: Why don't you just place all the form elements in one file?

Comment: Im trying to go in a plugin mode where anyone can add a widget to the system. hence this requirement